# Change SSRS subscription save path in bulk

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We are about to change one of the file servers and will be renaming it to something else. We have thousands of SSRS subscriptions saving reports to this server so I need to find a way of mass changing the destination server of where the reports end up. 
I've gone through the ReportServer tables and can't find anything obvious where i could do an UPDATE statement to change the destination server.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel i may have asked a question that will have fallen on death ears so let me explore my own findings. It appears under the Subscriptions table there is a field called ExtensionSettings, I'm confident this is linked to it

Comment: Ok it was a bold one, but I backed up and did a giant REPLACE(@OLDserver, @newserver) update on the Extensions table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ExtensionSettings FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions]
```

will give you the current paths. Backup first!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to know the exact code in the future:

```
UPDATE dbo.Subscriptions
SET ExtensionSettings=REPLACE(convert(varchar(max),ExtensionSettings),'OLDSERVER','NEWSERVER') 
where ExtensionSettings LIKE '%OLDSERVER%'
```

And may I stress........ BACKUP BEFORE THIS